# how to resolve the repeated commit with shiro?

Tags: java, spring, shiro

in spring, i made a HandlerInterceptor to resolve repeated commit from requests, 
when i tried to integrate shiro in spring, i found a question,that is if i use anon filter to made the repeated commit(e.g /login) the code works well,but if i use my custom filter to deal with the requests, the requests always pending...

handlerInterceptor:

```
public class RepeatSubmitHandler implements HandlerInterceptor {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    log.info("preHandler was working....");
  }

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
    log.info("afterCompletion was working...");
  }
}
```

shiroConfig:

```
@Bean("shiroFilter")
public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shirFilter(SecurityManager securityManager) {
    ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
    shiroFilter.setSecurityManager(securityManager);

    Map<String, Filter> filters =  shiroFilter.getFilters();
    filters.put("oauth2", new OAuth2Filter());
    shiroFilter.setFilters(filters);

    Map<String, String> filterMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(); 
    //anon filter, shiro default filter
    filterMap.put("/api/sys/login", "anon"); 
    //custom filter
    filterMap.put("/**", "oauth2"); 
    shiroFilter.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterMap);

    return shiroFilter;
}
```

controller:

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public RestResponse login(@RequestBody SysLoginVo loginForm) {
    log.info("login was working...");
}

@GetMapping("/nav")
public RestResponse nav() throws InterruptedException {
    log.info("nav was working...");
}
```

console with anon filter to deal with repeated commit: it is my purpose

```
    preHandler was working....
    login was working...

    preHandler was working....
    preHandler was working....
    preHandler was working....

    afterCompletion was working...
```

console with custom filter to deal with repeated commit:

```
    preHandler was working....
    nav was working...
    afterCompletion was working...

    preHandler was working....
    nav was working...
    afterCompletion was working...
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, it's my fault,the reason is not about shiro,only for get request, for sending get request,the request will be pending status